# Read data from a file into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have a file `read.txt` with records like this

```
pulp_fiction
Pulp Fiction
jurassic_park
Jurassic Park
inception
Inception
```

I want to read these content of the file to an associative array like this in quest.php

```
<?php
 $quest ["pulp_fiction"] = "Pulp Fiction";
 $quest ["jurassic_park"] = "Jurassic Park";
 $quest ["inception"] = "Inception";
```

this is the code that opens the file for writing in the quest.php I need help in the array part. thks

```
<?php
$myFile = "read.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
$assoc_array = array();
$my_array = explode("\n", $theData);
foreach($my_array as $line)
{
    $tmp = explode("\n", $line);
    $assoc_array[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
fclose($fh);

// well the op wants the results to be in $quest
$quest = $assoc_array;
?>
```

I have this section of code saved as quest.php and am calling in quiz.php but when I try to match the image title with the actual title, nothing populates.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a slicker way, but this was my first thought:

```
$lines = file("read.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$pairs = array_chunk($lines, 2);

foreach($pairs as $array) {
    $quest[$array[0]] = $array[1];
}
```

Needs some var and error checking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/^(.*)\n(.*)/m', file_get_contents('read.txt'), $items);
$quest = array_combine($items[1], $items[2]);
```

Here, we use `preg_match` with a regex that matches the contents of a line, then a newline, and then the contents of that line, which has the effect of giving us two arrays, one with contents of even lines, one with odd lines.

A slightly more robust version which will check for "key" lines that only contain lowercase alphanumeric characters and underscores:

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/^([a-z_]+)\n(.*)/m', file_get_contents('lists.txt'), $match);
$quest = array_combine($match[1], $match[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, i hope this help.

```
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file.txt'));
$quest = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i+=2)
{
   $quest[$lines[$i]] = $lines[$i+1];
}
```

Comment: This gets the output that I want, but for some bizarre reason it isn't working....